# I want to add my jQuery file separate from my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to write cleaner and readable code, so I wanted to implement my [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code in a separate file. I saved the file in the sam folder as the jQuery code I downloaded from jquery.com. In my [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) I put the reference in there, and it does not work, but if I leave the jQuery code in my HTML it works.

My HTML code is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>focusin demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My jQuery code is in a separate file called `test.js` and follows:

```
$(':text').focusin(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

But when I run it in my browser it doesn't work. I basically tried everything and decided I need professional help.

Comment: First of, you don't need to add a DOM ready handler when the file is included after the elements in the DOM, so disregard those answers. Secondly, if the code works when it's added to the HTML, it should be fine, and the only other solution left is that the file isn't loading. Open the console in your browser (F12) and check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with relative links. Try changing this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need put your code in $(function() { ... });

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(':text').focusin(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first confirm inclusion of a file by putting the `alert()` function in the `test.js` file. If included then you can try writing some jQuery code in the `test.js` file to check whether the jQuery file is included properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ready handler for jQuery scripts, like

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').focusin(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    });
});
```